# Chrome extension: Icon is sliding to next line

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, google-chrome-extension

I want to show icon next to anchor link but it's sliding to next line. Following is the code:

```
$("a").each(function()
{
    var href = this.href;
    href = href.trim();
    console.log(href);
    if(isMatched(href))
    {
        var a = chrome.extension.getURL("amazing-icon.png");
        $(this).after('<span style="float:left;display:inline;width:8px;background-color:yellow;"><img style=";" width=8 height=8 src="'+a+'" alt="external link"/></span>');
    }
})
```

Comment: Hm, it should work. Did you try `before` instead of `after`?

Comment: @devnull69 I will try and let you know

Comment: Why is this particular to chrome extensions? (Other than the image url?)

Comment: @ZigMandel because right now I am using jQuery in Chrome extension

Comment: @devnull69 No it is not working

Comment: Can you try to create a minimalistic example with which you reproduce the issue on Chrome in jsfiddle.net or jsbin.com? I tried to create one but it seems to work fine, even with .after(). There must be additional CSS style settings that we cannot know about without the relevant code